# Alignment in math environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

Consider the following piece of code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A_i &= B_i + C_i\\
&= D_i + E_i+F_i + G_i + H_i\\
&= I_i + J_i+K_i + L_i\\
&\hspace{5.5em},\;i=1,\dotsc,m
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output using `pdfLaTeX`

[image]

I would like to automatically align the final line, i.e., `i=1,...,m`, exactly as in the previous picture (in this example far right is at `H_i`), without manually setting an `\hspace{xx}` each time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `alignat` to introduce multiple alignment points:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  A_i &= B_i + C_i \\
      &= D_i + E_i+F_i + G_i + H_i \\
      &= I_i + J_i+K_i + L_i \\
      &                           &&i = 1,\dotsc,m
\end{alignat*}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

The above introduces a left-alignment of `i=...`. To obtain a right-alignment, use `\llap{$i = 1,\dotsc,m$}`. This introduces a `l`eft over`lap` at the correct alignment position:

[image]

```
%...
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  A_i &= B_i + C_i \\
      &= D_i + E_i + F_i + G_i + H_i \\
      &= I_i + J_i + K_i + L_i \\
      &                             &&\llap{$i = 1,\dotsc,m$}
\end{alignat*}
%...
```

An illustration of the different alignment options using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is given in Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode). See section **25 `align` environments** (p 43):

[image]